# Cannot create Q# projects

Tags: visual-studio-2019, q#

I'm new to quantum computing and I've been trying to follow instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-command-line-qdk?tabs=tabid-vscode to dive into this field, but I've run into a problem. Every time I'm trying to create a new Q# application project, I get the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPabE.png)

> The project file cannot be opened. Unable to find package Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.

and I can't find that package myself either.

I've tried to install Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit-0.16.2104.138035 several times, with both .NET 3.1.408 and 5.0.202. I'm using VS 2019 16.9.4 Community Edition on Windows 10.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the project file that you're attempting to build? In general, the Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk package is not installed on the machine, but is referenced from a specific project. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like nuget.org is not listed as a valid package source in your computer, so dotnet can't find the QDK packages online.

Try running this command:

```
dotnet nuget add source  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org
```

And then try building your Q# project again.

It's unclear to me why `nuget.org` is not listed as a source, though; it should be included by default when you install the .NET Core.